# HTTPクライアントからアクセスに応じてプログラムを実行

Tags: python, python3

表記の件に関しまして、その結果をHTTPレスポンスとして返せる運勢ページを作成しましたが、エラーがでまして上手くいきません。
今日の運勢プログラムのコードは以下の通りです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

html_body='''<html>
　<head>
　　<meta charset="UTF-8">
　　<title>Today's fortune</title>
　</head>
　<body>
you are {} today
　</body>
</html>

todays_fortune=random.choice(['lucky','unlucky','bad','not bad','fuck'])

print('content-type:text/html')
print('')
print(html_body.format(todays_fortune))
```

実行権限を与えるコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
$chmod +x fortune.py
```

webサーバーの起動は以下の通りです。

```
$python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

URLは以下の通りです。
http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/fortune.py

webサーバー上でのエラーは次の通りです。

```
Message: No such CGI script ('/cgi-bin/fortune.py').
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

当方初学者でありまして、質問が意味をなしてないこともあると思いますが、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: command+Kにてインデントをつけようとするのですが上手くいきません。質問でコードを書くときは、コピペではなくcommand+Kを使いながら全て書かないと反映されないのでしょうか？

Comment: インデントはCtrl+Kです。参考：https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%82%84%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AB%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fortune.py`を保存する`cgi-bin`ディレクトリをつくっていないのではないですか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
cgi-binのディレクトリは作っています。

Comment: こちらの質問ですが無事解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました。